# VSTS Security Settings to Allow/Deny access to Load Testing

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing

Are there settings available to Allow/Deny user access to the 'Test - Load Testing' feature within VSTS?  As of 5/3/2018, it appears that this feature is in Preview mode with an alert that:

> > 'Create and run high-scale load tests, analyze results – all using the browser! Learn more. During preview, this feature is available to all users (except Stakeholders).

Since Load Testing can incur costs, we'd like to Disable this feature for majority of the individuals which have access to our account.  I have search Stackoverflow & MSDN Developer Community with no success.

Please advise.

Thank you, 
- Brendan

Answer (score 0):

No such feature now, you can vote this user voice: [load test permission](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34150504-load-test-permission)